# Java - org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V while trying to make a Excel Sheet, gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, apache-poi, nosuchmethoderror

So, I have this application where data is sent to me and I have to make it into an Excel sheet. I use Eclipse IDE, I do not have any errors in the code I have written.
But it gives an exception at setBold(bold) method. 
Here is the stacktrace

```
Sep 27, 2017 5:03:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/<appName>] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V
at <fullpath>.Excel.setCurrentFont(Excel.java:177)
```

Now, I know that setBold(boolean bold) accepts only Boolean values. I have not made any error wherever in my code. The stacktrace points a Line in Excel.java which is given below...

```
public void setCurrentFont(String fontName, short fontSize, boolean bold,
        boolean italic, short colorIndex, short offset, byte underline) {
    Font font = wb.createFont();
    font.setFontName(fontName);
    font.setBold(bold);
    font.setFontHeightInPoints(fontSize);
    font.setColor(colorIndex);
    font.setItalic(italic);
    font.setTypeOffset(offset);
    font.setUnderline(underline);
    currentFont = font;
}
```

By the stacktrace, `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V`, I think it is searching for a method `setBold(Z)V;` where Z, V are values (my assumption) but `setBold(boolean bold);` is the method in that poi?

I have been using

> org.apache.poi V 3.12
>   Eclipse IDE

Comment: Can u please check the import statement for Font class? Java awt package has Font class as well. Just to make sure that you have imported the correct one.

Comment: What happens if you [read and follow the Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that the Font class has been imported from the proper package `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;` and not from `java.awt.*` package.

Thank you @Gagravarr, I  am reading it. Will let you know soon