# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V

Tags: java, exception, apache-poi, xlsx

I am using

> apache poi 3.15.jar
>
> poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar

trying to create xlsx file from java code

**XSSFWorkbook**

I have used

```
        Font font = workbook.createFont();
        font.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setBold(true);// this line throws error
```

Or

```
        XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont myfont = workbook.createFont();
```

Both throws error
Error log:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V
```

I have referred

[Java - org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font.setBold(Z)V while trying to make a Excel Sheet, gives NoSuchMethodError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46447105/6032482) -> Dint help.

Comment: Have you tried adding poi-ooxml 3.15 to your classpath?

Comment: yes , no solution from it

Comment: [You almost certainly have an older version of Apache POI on your classpath....The best way to identify the offending earlier jar files is with a few lines of java](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but could you try use variable of different type:

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook("myWorkbook.xlsx");

XSSFFont defaultFont= wb.createFont();
defaultFont.setFontName("Arial");
defaultFont.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
defaultFont.setBold(true);
```